# iOS) how to fix the image of default fbsdkloginbutton?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm not asking about customizing fbsdkloginbutton, I want to use default fbsdkloginbutton.

My problem is that after the button is clicked, the button's image changes, also action of button for logout.

But I just want to use that button to enter my app, not logging out.

So I want to fix the image of default fbsdkloginbutton for LogIn.

after or being executed method 'didCompleteWithResult', that button changes... How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use fbsdk login manger's code with your own uibutton and use the uibutton's image as you want.

FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login
    logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
    handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
      NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];

Comment: @ajay_nasa Is there any code to change uibutton issue? I can't find...

Comment: You should not try to reuse the FBSDKLoginButton the other purposes but loggin in with Facebook.